# How to test for EOL Exceptions in Python

Tags: python, exception, module, syntax-error, eol

I was wondering if there is a way to test for an EOL error so I can make a program that gives people more helpful information on how to fix certain errors. I have tried:

```py
import os
def suggest(file):
  try:
    os.system("python3 " + file)
  except:
    if SyntaxError and SyntaxError == "EOL":
      print("""EOL error. You either forgot a quotation mark or made an invalid new line. To fix this try putting a quotation mark at the end of the string or getting rid of new lines such as:
print("hello
world!")
into this:
print("hello world!")
If you must have newlines either use the escape character \\n or use triple quotation marks.
""")
      exit()
    else:
      print("No Errors Found.")
```

Comment: `except SyntaxError:`, not `if SyntaxError`. And definitivly not `SyntaxError == "EOL"`.  Eventually you can try `except SyntaxError as ex: if `"EOL" in str(ex):` but I don't know if it will works. You may also try to read about module `traceback` - maybe there is method to get more information about error.

Comment: i'm not sure if you can catch error in code which you run in `os.system("python3 " + file)`  because it runs in separated python interpreter so it doesn't send errors to current interpreter. I would rather expect catch error when run code directly  `eval(file.read())`